# Extract data from a base64 encoded PNG graph

Tags: graph, png, base64, ocr

I am trying to extract the actual data that is being used to generate a graph with X and Y axis. The graph is output to a PNG format which is base64 encoded. When decoding the base64, all I am getting is the PNG code, but nothing human readable. Is it possible to get the data itself and if so, what tools should be used to do so?

Comment: can you share a sample?

Comment: Which data are you referring to? The data inside the graph of a PNG? Keep in mind that PNG is a raster format, and you will need to process its data according to its pixel values. To view the base64 encoded image, you can do an online search for one like [Free Formatter's Base64 Encoder/Decoder](http://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html).

Comment: This is an example of the chat that I am trying to extract numbers from: [Chart Image Link](http://charts.camelcamelcamel.com/us/B00D7Z1Q9E/sales-rank.png?force=1&zero=0&w=725&h=440&legend=1&ilt=1&tp=all&fo=0&lang=en)

Basically, I would like to know what are the numbers used to generate the actual chart, so that I can then use for data gathering.

Comment: Reconstruct the original data points from which the green line is constructed? Hard, and very inaccurate to boot. (1) You can sample x,y coordinates of the green points; then (2) scale and transform them to a (0,0) point -- top left, for example. Scale by height and width of the graph part of the full image. But the resulting numbers are going to be *heavily* aliased, i.e., 'rounded' to pixel locations. Besides, you need to decide when to sample the top or the bottom of a vertical line.

Comment: So, the only way is to do a OCR scraping, but there is no way to actually get meaningful numbers from the base64 encoding itself?

Also, what if the graph is more detailed because vector scaled to bigger image, like here: [link to Bigger Scaled Image](http://charts.camelcamelcamel.com/us/B00D7Z1Q9E/sales-rank.png?force=1&zero=0&w=4000&h=3000&legend=1&ilt=1&tp=all&fo=0&lang=en)